# How to manage firebase UID as primary key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app which uses Firebase RealtimeDatabase and authentication, in my users table I use  the UID as the primary key which is associated with their specific device. The issue is when they try to log into their account on the website I have planned, how would I associate the web session to that user's UID?

Comment: The uid is unrelated to their specific device. uid is assigned by Firebase to that specific Auth user object *on the auth server* - that means no matter where or what device they log into firebase knows it's that user. Perhaps you have some code that adds something additional to tie it to a device? If so, can you share what that is and explain the implementation? In the meantime please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well that changes everything, I was taught that uid was specific to whatever device is used for authentication, thank you.